# Dual of the Hom Space Between Modules

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, modules

We know that if $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional $\mathsf{k}$-vector spaces, then we have the isomorphism

$$
 \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(V,W)^{*} \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(W,V).
$$

Now if we have a finite dimensional $\mathsf{k}$-algebra $A$, with finite dimensional $A$-modules $V$, and $W$, then can we say much about the $\mathsf{k}$-linear dual $\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W)^{*}$?

The naive approach would be that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W)^{*} = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}\left(\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W),\mathsf{k}\right) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(W,V),
$$
but this would imply, in particular, that $\dim_{\mathsf{k}}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W) = \dim_{\mathsf{k}}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(W,V)$ and I don't know if this holds in generality. Is this true? /  is there some way we can simplify $\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W)^{*}$?

——

Edit: My justification for believing this isn’t true is the following. Suppose that $V \to W$ is an $A$-algebra surjection onto an irreducible module $W$. Then if this result were true, by my dimension argument we must have $\dim_{\mathsf{k}}\operatorname{Hom}_A(W,V) > 0$, and so in particular there is some non zero $A$-algebra map $W \to V$, which is hence injective since $W$ is irreducible. In other words the result would imply that any irreducible quotient is also isomorphic to a submodule. This is clearly not true in generality? Hence the isomorphism

$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(V,W)^{*} \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(W,V),
$$

can not possibly in generality.

Comment: For finite dimensional vector spaces we also have $X^*\cong X$, and in particular $\hom_A(V,W)^*\cong\hom_A(V,W)$. Your first statement follows from the incidental fact $\hom_k(V,W)\cong\hom_k(W,V)$, which indeed doesn't generalize for modules.

Comment: I should have stated that I’m asking for natural isomorphisms here. Naturalist of the first statement comes from the natural vector space isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(V,W) \cong V^* \otimes W$. So whilst you’re correct that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(V,W)^* \cong \operatorname{Hom}_A(V,W)$, this isomorphism isn’t natural and so isn’t quite what I was after. Thanks though!

Comment: Where I say natural here, I might actually just mean canonical.

Comment: If you can define a $k$-linear trace function $\operatorname{tr}:\operatorname{Hom}_A(V,V) \to k$, then we have a map $\Phi:\operatorname{Hom}_A(W,V) \to \operatorname{Hom}_A(V,W)^*$ given by
$$
[\Phi(S)](T) = \operatorname{tr}(ST).
$$
I suspect that this map constitutes a "natural" isomorphism

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your comment. The map $\Phi$ you define is given by the pre and post compositions of the traditional isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(W,V) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(V,W)^{*}$ with the restrictions to the $\mathsf{k}$-subspaces $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{A}}(W,V) \subseteq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(W,V)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{A}}(V,W) \subseteq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{k}}(V,W)$. This gives a well-defined map, but its not clear to me why it remains an isomorphism following these restrictions?

Comment: I’ve edited the original post to add some justifications